# Compare two byte arrays and find which one is bigger

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays

I have a jagged byte array `byte[][]`, I'm trying to get the max value of it's sub array items.

I have created a method:

```
private byte[] Max(byte[][] arrBytes)
{
    var max = arrBytes[0];
    foreach (var arr in arrBytes)
    {
        if (max != null && arr != null)
            if () // => How to say max > arr
                max = arr;
    }
    return max;
}
```

How can I return the max byte array from the above method?

**Edit**
To all who asked what is the measure or definition of word `bigger` means I say that the jagged array contains (timestamp) datatype of SQLServer (varbinary(8)), the data looks like this

[image]

The byte array represent (ex: 0x00000000013F3F3F)

Comment: How do you define that one array is greater than another?

Comment: @BartoszKP If I knew the answer I wouldn't put the question here!

Comment: @SVI You told us you want to find which array is "bigger".  You have to define what bigger means to your application.  Bigger in terms of length (number of elements)?  Bigger in terms of the sum of all the elements?  You have to know what you want.

Comment: Do you want the array with the max length, max average, max maximum/minimum? Or do you want the array with maximum value of all bytes in the jagged array?

Comment: I think the problem is that the title is misleading. The question says max value and it looks like there is just one jagged array and the OP wants just the max value anywhere in the array. Maybe???

Comment: What's your criteria to idenitfy the bigger array?

Comment: @TrevorElliott The problem that the length of all sub array items are the same, so I can't say `length` it is, the items of sub array representing a `varbinary` (timestamp) in SQLServer so I don't know what's the best way to measure or define `bigger`

Comment: @SVI There is no way to measure what is "bigger" for an array itself, only for the length or the sum of its contents or some other criteria.  There is a reason that arrays in C# do not overload and support the greater than and less than operators `>` and `<`.  If the length is the same then they are both the same size in terms of memory size.

Comment: BTW, your test for `max != null` doesn't make any sense. You already set max = arrBytes[0] and if arrBytes was empty, you would have thrown an exception there.

Comment: @SVI Since you don't know what you mean by "bigger" how are we supposed to know?  Why do you need to know this, for what purpose?

Comment: I think you should be trying to convert the `byte[]` into the timestamp value and comparing those to find the maximum.

Comment: @MattBurland I know that, that just a snippet

Comment: You still haven't really explained what bigger means, but there are a whole bunch of conversion functions to turn byte arrays into various lengths of numeric values. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066.aspx). Perhaps that would help? But beware of byte order differences.

Comment: @SVI So you want *some* aggregate of the values of the array. But unless you'll say clearly what aggregate exactly, how do you expect anyone to guess? Now you say that you really want to convert `byte[]` to timestamp - so why would you formulate your question in such a confusing way?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps converting to `long` and comparing would help you?

```
// Note: you should ensure that the arrays have at least 8 bytes!
// Although from your edits, it sounds like your "jagged" array isn't jagged at all
if (BitConverter.ToUInt64(max,0) > BitConverter.ToUInt64(arr,0)) 
{
    // do whatever.
}
```

But beware of byte order differences. This will work if your timestamp is simply a number of ticks. If it's actually a date, you'll need to figure out the appropriate conversion.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?

```
    private byte[] Max(byte[][] arrBytes)
    {
        byte[] max = new byte[arrBytes.GetLength(0)];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (byte[] arr in arrBytes)
        {
            byte m = 0;
            foreach (byte b in arr)
            {
                m = Math.Max(m, b);
            }
            max[i] = m; ++i;
        }
        return max;
    }
```